# Dynamic Timestamp DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, db2

Using DB2 SQL

I would like to query for records since 2:00 yesterday. I want a dynamic expression that frees me from having to manually enter the current date prior to running the query. The created_datetime attribute is of timestamp dataype.

For example:

```
select record_key, other_stuff
from table
where created_datetime > "2 o'clock PM yesterday"
```

Is this kind of dynamic timestamp comparison even possible? Eventually, I'd like to be able to do a window of time, which gets complicated!

```
select count(1)
from table
where created_datetime between "2 o'clock PM yesterday" and "2 o'clock PM today"
```

I am familiar with current date, but I am trying to conceptualize how I would leverage that. The following gets me close, but it includes everything 24 hours prior to whenever the query is run.

```
select count(1)
from table
where created_datetime between (currentdate - 1 day) and (currentdate @ 2 o'clock PM)
```

I know this is some pretty basic territory, and I feel guilty posting this question, but my research has not turned up anything for me so far. I appreciate every ounce of time spent on my behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
select record_key, other_stuff
from table
where created_datetime > CURRENT DATE - 10 HOURS

select count(1)
from table
where created_datetime between (CURRENT DATE - 10 HOURS) and (CURRENT DATE + 14 HOURS)

select count(1)
from table
where created_datetime between (CURRENT DATE - 1 DAYS) and (CURRENT DATE + 14 HOURS)
```

From the IBM Dev Works Library : [DB2 Basics: Fun with Dates and Times](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html)

There are heaps of samples there.

E.g.

> You can also perform date and time calculations using, for lack of a
>   better term, English:

```
current date + 1 YEAR 
current date + 3 YEARS + 2 MONTHS + 15 DAYS 
current time + 5 HOURS - 3 MINUTES + 10 SECONDS
```

Comment: I can't believe I failed to realize current date could be used that way. It's acts a lot like a constant based upon the day I'm running the query, and then I can just statically go back 10 hours and forward 14 hours.

Comment: I'm a SQL Server person, but I like it too, it'a great syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with this Timestamp option in you where clause.

Below sample to query for between last 24 hours.

```
select  
   timestamp(CURRENT date - 1 days,(CURRENT time - 24 hours)),
   timestamp(CURRENT date,CURRENT time ) 
FROM 
   sysibm.sysdummy1;
```